# Calculating partial sum of binomial coefficients fast

Tags: algorithms, binomial-coefficients

Although there does not exist closed formula for the partial sum of binomial coefficient, $\sum_{i=0}^k \left(
  \begin{array}{c}
   n \\
   i
  \end{array}
\right)$

, is it possible to calculate this faster than $O(k)$?

Comment: For $k>n/2$ you can get it $O(n-k)$

Comment: I don't think you'll get constant time if that's what you're looking for. There are some good bounds out there though.

Comment: For large $n$ you could approximate this as (constant multiple of) a normal distribution and use a table to find the area.

Comment: For large $n$ and $k\ll n$, you can have approximations.

Comment: What *exactly* does "calculate" mean here? (What are the units of complexity?)